# Facing issue while applying loadmask to tab panel

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to apply `ext.getBody.loadmask()` on tab panel change event as follows:

```
listeners : {           
    beforetabchange : function( tabPanel, newCard, oldCard){
        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        Ext.getBody().mask("please wait..");
    },
    tabchange : function( tabPanel, newCard, oldCard){
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
    }
}
```

But mask is getting activated without debugging after tabchange event but if I debug, I am able to see the mask.

Comment: If you don't "see" the mask, it's because the browser hasn't had any time to repaint, so busy loop is keeping it from drawing the mask to the screen.

Comment: I am making network call like loading grid in other tab after that tabchange event occurs

Comment: You want to unmask when grid finishes loading? Consider that changing tab doesn't wait to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The action is happening too fast when there is no debug, to see it in action without a debug you need to add a defer of 1 sec.

A working [Fiddle Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l5j)

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    title: 'Tab Panel',
    width: 700,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        title: 'tab1',
        html: 'tab1 content'
    }, {
        title: 'tab2',
        html: 'tab2 content'
    }],
    listeners: {
        beforetabchange: function (tabPanel, newCard, oldCard) {
            Ext.suspendLayouts();
            Ext.getBody().mask("please wait..");
        },
        tabchange: function (tabPanel, newCard, oldCard) {
            Ext.defer(function () {
                Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
                Ext.getBody().unmask();
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: But u see mask is not getting activated in  before tab change event if we put an alert in beforetabchange event after masking it is not showing masking.It is only getting activated after tabchange

Answer (score 0):

After some research I did't find simple solution.
So I implemented reactivating tab after loadMask will be rendered.

```
listeners: {
    beforetabchange: function(me, newTab, oldTab)
    {
        if(newTab.rendered || me.renderMask)
        {
            delete me.renderMask;
            return;
        }

        // Show loadMask
        me.body.mask('Rendering...');
        me.renderMask = true;

        oldTab.hide();

        // Activate tab again after event loop
        setTimeout(() => me.setActiveTab(newTab), 0);

        // Cancel activation
        return false;
    },
    tabchange: function(me, newTab, oldTab)
    {
        // Hide loadMask
        me.body.unmask();
    }
}
```